# Golang Time parsing providing the format is returning wrong results

Tags: go, parsing, time, timezone

I've got a `t time.Time` which I'm converting to an specific timezone and from which I need to extract both date and time (separately) as strings as follows:

Data should look like: `2006-09-23`
Time should look like: `05:06:23`

I'm doing the following:

1. Setting `t` to the needed timezone:

```
var err error
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")

    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        t = t.In(loc)
    }
```

2. Setting up the format and converting it to string so I can extract its values:

```
format := "2006-01-02 15:03:04"
timestamp := t.Format(format)
timestampSlice := strings.Fields(timestamp)

fmt.Println(timestampSlice[0])
fmt.Println(timestampSlice[1])
```

But I'm getting unexpected results for time (date works fine):

When passing

```
time.Date(2021, time.Month(2), 21, 1, 10, 30, 0, time.UTC)
```

I'd expect
`2021-02-20` and `17:10:30`
but I'm getting:
`17:05:10` for the time

When passing

```
time.Date(2022, time.Month(8), 26, 22, 7, 30, 0, time.FixedZone("Asia/Shanghai", 0)),
```

I'd expect
`2022-08-26` and `06:07:30`
but I'm getting:
`15:03:07`

what am I doing wrong? does the values passed in the format have any effect in the parsing? I thought the format was only to signal the way the result should look

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-Time.Format):

```golang
    // Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST
    //   1 2  3  4  5    6  -7
```

So the format `2006-01-02 15:03:04` would be parsed as `years-months-days hours-hours-minutes`. Note that `15` refers to the hours (00-23), that `03` refers to the hours (1-12), and `04` refers to the minutes.

So the correct format would be

```golang
format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
```

You can learn more about formatting time here: https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-Time.Format

Comment: that worked, thanks. Care to explain why my format was wrong?

Comment: the `03` in your time format refers to the current hour (12h version), and the `04` to current minute.

Comment: Sorry, still don't quite understand. Why `03` would be referring to the hour? shouldn't be `15` referring to the hour? why it is being ignored?

Comment: Both 15 and 3 refer to the hour, however 15 refers to it in 24h format, and `3` in a 12hour format